# Printing a list with a grammatically correct "and"

Tags: python, string

I'd like to print a list in a grammatically correct way, with correct usage of "and" before the last element.

Specifically, I'd like to turn a list like `[1, 2, 3]` into the string `"1, 2, and 3"`.

At the moment, I can do this:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
the_list = map(str, the_list)
string = ", ".join(the_list)
comma_location = string.rfind(", ") + 1
string = string[:comma_location] + " and" + string[comma_location:]
```

Isn't there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Do you care about the special cases where the list has 2 or 1 elements (or none!), or are you happy that it's fairly obvious how to handle those?

Comment: @SteveJessop Those can be handled with other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
tests = [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], ["first", "second", "third", "forth"]

for test in tests:
    print ', '.join(map(str, test[:-1])) + (' and ' if len(test) > 1 else '') + str(test[-1])
```

Giving:

```
1
1 and 2
1, 2 and 3
first, second, third and forth
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
print ', '.join(the_list[:-1]) + ' and ' + the_list[-1]
```

Comment: @Hammerite OP already said this is not a problem in a comment. `< 2` can be handled outside

Comment: Alright. Seems horrid though. Functionality should be inside a method that doesn't care whether there are 0, 1, or many elements.

Comment: I like that this doesn't use `map`, which IMO is way overused.

Comment: @Hammerite Fair enough, but this isn't even a function, it's just an idea for "pythonic" code.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[1, 2, 3]
import re
print re.sub(r",(?!.*,)",", and ",", ".join(map(str,l)))
```

Comment: Would this work for lists of other things besides ints?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the list contents are integers, you need to explicitly convert the data types to string before doing concatenation.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ', '.join(map(str,l[:-1])) + ', and '+ str(l[-1])
'1, 2, and 3'
>>>
```

Comment: @What if `len(l) < 2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This should handle the cases where there are 1 or 2 elements in `the_list`.

```
the_list = [str(x) for x in the_list] 
if len(the_list)>2:
    string = ', '.join(the_list[:-1]) + ', and ' + the_list[-1]
else:
    string = the_list[0] + ' and ' + the_list[1] if len(the_list)==2 else the_list[0]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> string
'1, 2, 3, and 4'

>>> the_list = [1, 2]
>>> string
'1 and 2'

>>> the_list = [1]
>>> string
'1'
```